# how do i get power armour training in fallout new vegas

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I have blown up the brother of steel and I cant do arcades quest is their any other ways of getting power armour traning

Comment: Hi and welcome to Arqade :) I hope the linked question we provided helps you find the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Though if you've closed off both those quests, there is no way to get power armor, short of using a console command to add the perk.